# Hide iFrame with Javascript obfuscator

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to hide my iFrame with Javascript. So basically I made the html string I need equal to a variable in JS and I am pasting it with `document.write(x)`

```
    var x = '<iframe src="http://google.com" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute"></iframe>'
document.write(x)
```

and then I obfuscated it that it will look like this :

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('6 7=\'<0 5="4://2.3" 8="1" 9="1" e="d:c;a:b"></0>\'',15,15,'iframe||google|com|http|src|var|x|width|height|position|absolute|hidden|visibility|style'.split('|'),0,{}))
document.write(x)
```

yet It's not working as when I open the Site I dont see any attempt in the sources that it load google.com

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Does it work without the obfuscation? BTW, hidden iframes sound bad top my ear.

Comment: I am getting this on my Chrome console : Refused to display 'https://www.google.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: This means you can't put Google inside a frame on another site, for security reasons Google disables this by setting the `X-Frame-Origin` header. You could try with another site.